# What is the term for an "inverse function" that returns sets when the original function is many-to-one?

Tags: functions, terminology, inverse, inverse-function

The notion of $f^{-1}$, so far as I have seen it treated, seems to only be defined for intervals where $f$ is one-to-one. I imagine there's a more general concept for the function that describes the set of all possible origin points.

I found the term "full inverse" online but only the site that used it itself showed up when searching for other references using it in the same context. I wonder if there's another more common name for such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}(A)=\{x \mid f(x) \in A\}$ is called the *inverse image* or *preimage* of $A$ under $f$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my answer to include both terms.